# Configure jms on WebSphere MQ using java without User and Password Data

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

I am developing a JMS application with IBM MQ in java; for this configure the following data;

```
        // Create a connection factory
        JmsFactoryFactory ff = JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(WMQConstants.WMQ_PROVIDER);
        JmsConnectionFactory cf = ff.createConnectionFactory();

        // Set the properties
        cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_HOST_NAME, server_Mq);
        cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_PORT, port_Mq);
        cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CHANNEL, channel_Mq);
        cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
        cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, qmgr_Mq);
        cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_APPLICATIONNAME, "JmsPutGet (JMS)");
        cf.setBooleanProperty(WMQConstants.USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP, false);//Change to true if password is not empty
        cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.USERID, app_User_Mq);
        cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.PASSWORD, app_Password_Mq);
```

But in the data they gave me I only have

```
server_Mq="10.224.10.20";
channel_Mq="SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN";
qmgr_Mq="TA.AS.QM.TEST";
queue_Name_Mq="AIRCOM2AMOS.ACARS.IN";
port_mq=1415;
```

Could I make the connection without the username and password?
Why I can do this?

I appreciate the response.

Comment: You can do this because authorization on server could be disabled.
Or ConnectionFactory uses defaultUsername to connect to WebSphereMQ

Comment: What version of IBM MQ is the queue manager.   If you are not using TLS certs for mutual authentication then you can do this because they likely do not have any true any authentication configured.   It could be anywhere from completely open to having some IP address based restriction [CHLAUTH rules] in place.   I would recommend they configure CONNAUTH+TLS or TLS w/ mutual authentication mapped to a user.

Comment: Why not ask your MQ Administratir for UID/PWD?

Comment: It may simply be that your queue manager is not secure and that is why you can do this. You may want to make this point to them? Perhaps it is a test server and they don't care. You can develop your application using it, and then later you will have to apply security once they let you test against a secure queue manager.